# How to show breadcrumbs for taxonomy terms in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I've just now started working on D7 but I can't figure out how to display the terms in the breadcrumbs as we do in D6( I guess using Taxonomy breadcrumb). Taxonomy breadcrumb module for D7 is in dev release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Taxonomy Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails) module. its better than 'Taxonomy breadcrumb'.